# Elastic Logging plugin for Docker: "error creating logger", "hosts flag is required"

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, docker-logs

Running Docker 20.10.22 on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy.

I'm trying to configure my Docker containers to log to Elastic Cloud, either by default through the mechanism of `/etc/docker/daemon.json` or through the use of command line flags.

I have tried with a daemon file like this:

```
me@server:~$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "log-driver": "elastic/elastic-logging-plugin:8.5.3",
  "log-opts": {
    "cloud_id": "...",
    "api_key": "...",
    "output.elasticsearch.index": "dockerlogs-wiki-%{+yyyy.ww}",
    "max-file": "10",
    "max-size": "4M"
  }
}
```

The Elastic Logging plugin is available and enabled:

```
me@server:~$ docker plugin ls
ID             NAME                                   DESCRIPTION              ENABLED
54832cf3f8f6   elastic/elastic-logging-plugin:8.5.3   A beat for docker logs   true
```

After restarting Docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker` to load the `daemon.json` I get this:

```
me@server:~$ docker create --name=container-name -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro --restart=unless-stopped -h container-name --network=mynetwork ghcr.io/org/container-name:latest
09e3001a8a5507be2aa0cca44d3e9735dd7a6f4c3c59bb9f5a35c941f74fe240
me@server:~$ docker start container-name
Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: error creating logger: LogDriver.StartLogging: error creating client config: A hosts flag is required
Error: failed to start containers: container-name
```

I also tried with no daemon file, just CLI flags:

```
me@server:~$ docker create --name=container-name \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  -h container-name \
  --network=wikinet \
  --log-driver=elastic/elastic-logging-plugin:8.5.3 \
  --log-opt cloud_id="..." \
  --log-opt api_key="..." \
  --log-opt max-file=10 \
  --log-opt max-size=5M \
  ghcr.io/org/container-name:latest
09e3001a8a5507be2aa0cca44d3e9735dd7a6f4c3c59bb9f5a35c941f74fe240
me@server:~$ docker start container-name
Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: error creating logger: LogDriver.StartLogging: error creating client config: A hosts flag is required
Error: failed to start containers: container-name
```

Same result. Any ideas on how to debug this would be more than welcome.

Comment: Did some experimentation, this is actually a problem with the plugin config, not with Docker. Editing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `--log-opt hosts=""` makes the error go away and logs appear in Elastic Cloud. Shouldn't be necessary, but here we are.